# Clone object with linq-to-object

Tags: clone, linq-to-objects

Does exist the possibility to clone an object coming from a linqToOject query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You can call any method in a LINQ-to-Objects query, including `Clone()`.

To answer the question, no; that won't happen.

Comment: ok, I need to implement the Clone method from by implementing the IClonable interface